# In SceneKit, how widely different are the iOS10 and iOS11 implementations?

Tags: scenekit, xcode9-beta

The same program run on the iOS10 simulator and the iOS11 simulator renders very differently.  Is there a good summary of the non-back-compatible deltas, or how to have one SceneKit program generate the same output on the different iOS versions?

[image: iOS10 rendering]

[image: iOS11 rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now it seems you can't read back a nodes euler angles (only get zeroes for pitch, yaw & roll). So if you try to rotate your node based on its initial euler angles it will be wrong.

Comment: That would explain the difference in orientation, as well as a few other anomalies I'm seeing but didn't ask about.  Thanks.  By the way, how did you discover this?!

Comment: I kind of had the same problem, so I printed out the angle values, and on iOS 8-10 you can read out the initial angles, on iOS 11 beta you get zeroes.